# Black screen on capturing screenshots for some failed tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a method to capture screenshots whenever a test method fails. I have put that method in @BeforeMethod annotation so that it runs before every @test annotation. And I have 8 @test annotations. Issue is, whenever some tests fail, my code captures screenshots but they are just a black screen. Interestingly this happens only for some failed tests, and for the other failed tests the screenshot is proper. For example: if 4 out of 8 tests have failed, then only 2 failed tests display blank screen other 2 display the proper screenshot. Need help to fix this issue.

Specs: I am running the code in my local machine,on Eclipse and Java language. and my browser is IE11

Comment: Study this issue: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3536 It may help

Comment: Did you do any thing while your code run? Ex: turn on a program to override on your browser, or minimize your browser while it running?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen - No, I did not touch the browser when code is running